# Why is Alpha "FromArgb" casuing issues in LinearGradientBrush?

Tags: c#, colors

I want to generate a `LinearGradientBrush` with 100 GradientStops using rainbow colors.

to do so I am doing

```
public static LinearGradientBrush CreateRainbowBrush()
        {
            var brush = new LinearGradientBrush { StartPoint = new System.Windows.Point(0, 0), EndPoint = new System.Windows.Point(1, 0) };
            int colorCount = 100;
            double step = 1 / colorCount;
            List<Color>  rainbow = GetRainbowColors(colorCount);
            for (int i = 0; i < colorCount; i++, step += step)
            {
                brush.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(rainbow.ElementAt(i) , step);                
            }
            return brush;
        }
```

The issue is that following method is returning values like

```
FFFF0000
FFFF03D0
...
```

Those are correct, but I figured out, when using in my own method I am getting gray scales, like if I would take

```
FFFF00
FFFF03
```

which is not correct

The code to convert hue to color is:

```
public static List<Color> GetRainbowColors(int colorCount)
    {
        List<Color> ret = new List<Color>(colorCount);

        double p = 360.0 / (double)colorCount;

        for (int n = 0; n < colorCount; n++)
        {
            ret.Add(HsvToRgb(n * p, 1.0, 1.0));
        }

        return ret;
    }
    public static Color HsvToRgb(double h, double s, double v)
    {
        int hi = (int)Math.Floor(h / 60.0) % 6;
        double f = (h / 60.0) - Math.Floor(h / 60.0);

        double p = v * (1.0 - s);
        double q = v * (1.0 - (f * s));
        double t = v * (1.0 - ((1.0 - f) * s));

        Color ret;

        switch (hi)
        {
            case 0:
                ret = GetRgb(v, t, p);
                break;
            case 1:
                ret = GetRgb(q, v, p);
                break;
            case 2:
                ret = GetRgb(p, v, t);
                break;
            case 3:
                ret = GetRgb(p, q, v);
                break;
            case 4:
                ret = GetRgb(t, p, v);
                break;
            case 5:
                ret = GetRgb(v, p, q);
                break;
            default:
                ret = Color.FromRgb(0x00, 0x00, 0x00);
                break;
        }
        ret = Color.FromRgb (ret.R, ret.G, ret.B);
        return ret;
    }
    public static Color GetRgb(double r, double g, double b)
    {
        return Color.FromRgb ((byte)(r * 255.0), (byte)(g * 255.0), (byte)(b * 255.0));
    }
```

what the heck am I missing, how to remove the **a** from rgb!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your algo takes a range for H of 0 to 360 !

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication4
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
        }

        private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var rectangle = new Rectangle();
            rectangle.Fill = CreateRainbowBrush(100);
            Content = rectangle;
        }

        public static LinearGradientBrush CreateRainbowBrush(int colors)
        {
            var brush = new LinearGradientBrush
            {
                StartPoint = new Point(0, 0),
                EndPoint = new Point(1, 0)
            };

            for (var i = 0; i < colors; i++)
            {
                var d = 1.0d/colors*i;
                var h = d*360.0d;
                var s = 1.0d;
                var v = 1.0d;
                var hsvToRgb = HsvToRgb(h, s, v);
                brush.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(hsvToRgb, d));
            }
            return brush;
        }

        public static Color HsvToRgb(double h, double s, double v)
        {
            var hi = (int) Math.Floor(h/60.0)%6;
            var f = h/60.0 - Math.Floor(h/60.0);

            var p = v*(1.0 - s);
            var q = v*(1.0 - f*s);
            var t = v*(1.0 - (1.0 - f)*s);

            switch (hi)
            {
                case 0:
                    return ToColor(v, t, p);
                case 1:
                    return ToColor(q, v, p);
                case 2:
                    return ToColor(p, v, t);
                case 3:
                    return ToColor(p, q, v);
                case 4:
                    return ToColor(t, p, v);
                case 5:
                    return ToColor(v, p, q);
                default:
                    return Colors.Black;
            }
        }

        public static Color ToColor(double r, double g, double b)
        {
            return Color.FromRgb((byte) (r*255.0), (byte) (g*255.0), (byte) (b*255.0));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't spend much time trying to figure out the specific problem in your code. The code you posted doesn't compile, and once I got it running, I found that every `Color` value generated had an alpha value of `0xff` just as expected. I don't know how to interpret your question:

> how to remove the **a** from rgb!?

Remove how? What *"**a**"* are you talking about?

I did notice various math irregularities, but it seemed like it would require reinventing the algorithm from scratch to narrow down the specific problem (though I see someone else did, and significantly cleaned up your code as well).

Mainly though, it seems to me you're going about this all wrong. There's no reason to create so many stops, because WPF will happily interpolate them from raw colors for you. And there's no need to write code to do this, because you can easily declare the whole thing in XAML:

```xml
<Window x:Class="TestSO39157294Rainbow.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestSO39157294Rainbow"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.Resources>
        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="rainbowBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0">
            <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="0.16667"/>
            <GradientStop Color="Lime" Offset="0.33333"/>
            <GradientStop Color="Cyan" Offset="0.5"/>
            <GradientStop Color="Blue" Offset="0.66666"/>
            <GradientStop Color="Magenta" Offset="0.83333"/>
            <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Rectangle Fill="{StaticResource rainbowBrush}"/>
</Window>
```

Comment: While OP's algo seems different, actually it's not that much compared to http://www.easyrgb.com/index.php?X=MATH&H=21#text21 . I think there's a strong point in using code to generate a gradient compared to your method: no manual typing, any amount of stops, and it can be completely different from an HSV rainbow :)

Comment: @Aybe: _"no manual typing"_ -- huh? how do you think all that code gets into the program, if not "manual typing"? _"any amount of stops"_ -- there's no limitation in XAML either. The point is that there's no need for 100 different stops when seven do exactly the same thing. _" it can be completely different from an HSV rainbow "_ -- actually, it's _easier_ in XAML to produce gradient brushes "different from an HSV rainbow". Methinks your bias is showing.

Comment: I hope you'll agree that unless one uses Blend to generate a gradient using the mouse, typing it manually is really painful: you have to pick a color, convert to hex, compute the offset and so on. And I entirely agree on the fact that 100 stops are not necessary !

Comment: @Aybe: _"typing it manually is really painful"_ -- huh? It took me less than a minute to type the XAML above, and there's not a single hex value in sight. The hardest part was computing the offset, but that's not exactly rocket science. Anyone who doesn't have the decimal values for 1/3, 1/2, and 2/3 memorized, and who can't easily come up with 1/6 and 5/6 from those values, really ought not to be programming. Any scenario where hex values would be required, they'd be required when writing code for them as well.

Comment: We could argue for days :) I took the route of fixing his code instead of re-writing it in another way, it took around 5 mins and that wasn't really difficult. I'd conclude that both of our methods have pros and cons !

Comment: _"We could argue for days"_ -- only if you keep trying to invent "a strong point" in favor of your answer vs. mine. It's up to you.

Comment: Okay ... I am wrong and you are right if that's what you'd like to hear.

Comment: @Aybe: not sure what made you think I want or need "to hear" anything, never mind an insincere statement of concession. A more appropriate response would be to just delete all your comments, since they aren't adding anything useful here.